# ASP.net for both web development and desktop development?

Tags: asp.net, desktop

I'm just confused about this. Can c# ASP.net be used for both web development and desktop applications development? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two different - though related - things.

C# is a programming language. It can be used to develop web apps, desktop apps, services, etc.

ASP.NET is a web application framework based on the .NET framework. There are other parts of the .NET framework which are geared toward other types of programs, such as desktop apps (WPF and WinForms, for example) and services of many kinds.